# how do I use optional func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) to change text as it's entered?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2

At first I wanted to make an endless loop for it:

```
while stringLength == textView.text.characters.count{
                text.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: nsString.rangeOfString("hello"))
                    text.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: NSMakeRange(0, stringLength))
```

However someone pointed out to me the best way to go about changing text entered in TextView would be to use optional func `textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView)`.

I looked through apple documentation, a few tutorials, and a few google searches but none seem to tell me how exactly that would be done or how to use the optional function in general.

I don't mind reading so if anyone wants to point me toward the right documentation i'd be more than happy to look at it. I just haven't been able to find any myself. Extremely new to coding.

Comment: If you want to use NSAttributeString I recommend you use this library https://github.com/lsolniczek/string-in-chain is much simpler and intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

[UITextViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextViewDelegate/textViewDidEndEditing:)
It's a delegate function.
Import UITextViewDelegate protocol and simply use the function:

Answer (score 0):

In your class you should declare it:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextViewDelegate
```

and in viewDidLoad() set

```
self.textView.delegate = self
```

that way you can use your delegate methods.